# Get the custom post type data from wordpress database and display it quarterly

Tags: wordpress

I have two scenarios here display the data on the basis of  monthly 
Like 
January 2020 
 - Data 1      Data 1 Date
 - Data 2      Data 2 Date
February 2020
 - Data 3      Data 3 Date
 - Data 4      Data 4 Date

===============================================================================================

2nd Scenario needs to get the data quarterly 
Like 
January - March 2020
 - Data 1      Data 1 Date
 - Data 2      Data 2 Date

April - June 2020

- Data 3      Data 3 Date
- Data 4      Data 4 Date

Can someone please take a look

enter code here

Thanks

Comment: Do you have example mySQL queries you tried? 
What language(s) are you using to access the Database? Have you tried one of your scenarios in a script? If so could you please provide some code examples?

Comment: $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'email_newsletter',
            'paged' => get_query_var('paged')/*,
            'posts_per_page' => -1*/
        ); ?>

Comment: That's the query I am using in WordPress

Comment: Here is the code I am using for monthly content

Comment: $ref_month = '';
    $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'email_newsletter',
            'paged' => get_query_var('paged')/*,
            'posts_per_page' => -1*/
        ); ?>
<?php   

    $nbemails = new WP_Query($args); 
?>

Comment: <?php if($nbemails->have_posts()) : ?>
     <div class="newsletter-list-container page-container ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 medium-12 column">
        <?php while($nbemails->have_posts()) : $nbemails->the_post(); 

                if( get_the_date('mY') != $ref_month ) { 
                    if( $ref_month ) echo "\n".'</ul>';
                    echo "\n".'<h3 class="heading_H3">'.get_the_date('F Y').'</h3>';
                    echo "\n".'<ul class="nl-list">';
                    $ref_month = get_the_date('mY');
                }

Comment: echo "\n".'   <li><a href='.get_permalink($post->ID).'>'.get_the_title($post->ID).' <span class="nl-date">'.get_the_date('F d, Y').'</span></a></li>';
        ?>
                <!-- <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> -->
        <?php 
            endwhile; 
            echo "\n".'</ul>';
        ?>

Comment: Please edit your initial question and put the code there, in a properly formatted fashion. Furthermore, please explain what you expect the code to do, and what its not doing.

Comment: @Yserbius please take a look at this thread

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61871128/show-the-data-quarterly-from-the-database-in-wordpress-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the code I used for monthly content

```
$ref_month = '';
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'email_newsletter',
            'paged' => get_query_var('paged')/*,
            'posts_per_page' => -1*/
        ); ?>
<?php   

    $nbemails = new WP_Query($args); 
?>
    <?php if($nbemails->have_posts()) : ?>
     <div class="newsletter-list-container page-container ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 medium-12 column">
        <?php while($nbemails->have_posts()) : $nbemails->the_post(); 

                if( get_the_date('mY') != $ref_month ) { 
                    if( $ref_month ) echo "\n".'</ul>';
                    echo "\n".'<h3 class="heading_H3">'.get_the_date('F Y').'</h3>';
                    echo "\n".'<ul class="nl-list">';
                    $ref_month = get_the_date('mY');
                }

            echo "\n".'   <li><a href='.get_permalink($post->ID).'>'.get_the_title($post->ID).' <span class="nl-date">'.get_the_date('F d, Y').'</span></a></li>';
        ?>
                <!-- <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> -->
        <?php 
            endwhile; 
            echo "\n".'</ul>';
        ?>
```